# How to run a Python Script from another Python Script

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a python script which detects the motion from webcam or a video. 
I need a GUI to start this python script. I created my GUI by using PyQt5 Designer and I want to click a button to open my `motion_detector.py`

Here is my code.

I have a button in GUI

```
  self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
```

I try to open my motion_detector.py by clicking this button

```
  self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:os.system('python motion_detector.py'))
```

At the top of my code I imported `"os"` and also I put my GUI file `untitled.py` and my `motion_detector.py` in the same directory.
When I try to run it gives me an error

```
  python: can't open file 'motion_detector.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Write the absolute path to the Python file in the "os.system" call.

Comment: Or avoid the `os.system` and replace it with `import motion_detector as md ; md.its_main_function()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either subprocess or os modules.
I prefer subprocess since it's quieter and it stores for you the output and the error code (if there's one) - in both cases don't forget to put the full path to both your script and the python.exe (unless you put it's path to the %PATH% variable)

The syntax for os.system is:

```
os.system("<path to python> <path to your script>")
```

The syntax for subprocess.Popen is:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(t"<path to python>", "<path to your script>"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: You want to avoid a shell with `Popen`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: My bad forgot to add the shell=False.
Thanks for the comment!

Comment: That's not sufficient; you also have to convert the first argument to a list of strings. (Edited to fix.) But you really want to avoid `Popen` altogether for `run` or a similar higher-level function. See further https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188